# Parse json to Object java/groovy

Tags: java, json, groovy

I have following json with this format:

```
 [ 
    ["Rio Branco", "1200401", "MU", "01392", "Acre", "AC", 
        ["PSB", "Marina Silva", 115594, 58.34, "N"], 
        ["PSDB", "A\u00e9cio Neves", 44676, 22.55, "N"], 
        ["PT", "Dilma", 35802, 18.07, "N"], 
        ["PSOL", "Luciana Genro", 648, 0.33, "N"], 
        ["PSC", "Pastor Everaldo", 520, 0.26, "N"], 
        ["PV", "Eduardo Jorge", 346, 0.17, "N"], 
        ["PRTB", "Levy Fidelix", 332, 0.17, "N"], 
        ["PSDC", "Eymael", 155, 0.08, "N"], 
        ["PSTU", "Z\u00e9 Maria", 39, 0.02, "N"], 
        ["PCB", "Mauro Iasi", 25, 0.01, "N"], 
        ["PCO", "Rui Costa Pimenta", 6, 0.0, "N"]
    ]
 ]
```

How can I parse this json without key names?
Java codes or groovy/grails code.

I'm do this...

```
 def lista = new JsonSlurper().parseText(new File(jsonfilename).text) 
lista.each { 
          //here I want to read the properties of son, but how can I without the key name?? 
    }
```

Comment: This JSON document structure is the stuff of nightmares.

Comment: any clue?@rmlan

Comment: Sure. Do some research, write some code, and come back when you have a specific problem. This site is not for dumping a JSON document and asking us to write a parser for you.

Comment: :/
I'm do this...
 def lista = new JsonSlurper().parseText(new File(jsonfilename).text)
        
        lista.each {

      //here I want to read the properties of son, but how can I without the key name??

        }

Comment: Don't you think that code might have been relevant to your question? I think you should probably edit your question and add that code.

Comment: If you're not going to give names to the fields, why don't you just use CSV? This is not how JSON works.

Answer (score -1):

You need to reference each field by index. I'd suggest assigning each field to a map, which will make it easier to work with:

```
json =''' [ 
    ["Rio Branco", "1200401", "MU", "01392", "Acre", "AC", 
        ["PSB", "Marina Silva", 115594, 58.34, "N"], 
        ["PSDB", "A\u00e9cio Neves", 44676, 22.55, "N"], 
        ["PT", "Dilma", 35802, 18.07, "N"], 
        ["PSOL", "Luciana Genro", 648, 0.33, "N"], 
        ["PSC", "Pastor Everaldo", 520, 0.26, "N"], 
        ["PV", "Eduardo Jorge", 346, 0.17, "N"], 
        ["PRTB", "Levy Fidelix", 332, 0.17, "N"], 
        ["PSDC", "Eymael", 155, 0.08, "N"], 
        ["PSTU", "Z\u00e9 Maria", 39, 0.02, "N"], 
        ["PCB", "Mauro Iasi", 25, 0.01, "N"], 
        ["PCO", "Rui Costa Pimenta", 6, 0.0, "N"]
    ]
]'''

def result = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText json collect { uf ->
    [
        capital : uf[0],
        state: uf[4],
        candidates : uf[6..-1].collect { candidate ->
            [
                party : candidate[0],
                name : candidate[1]
            ]
        }
    ]
}

assert result[0].capital == "Rio Branco"
assert result[0].state == "Acre"
assert result[0].candidates[0].name == "Marina Silva"
assert result[0].candidates[4].party == "PSC"
```